# Multiple init files for a new Bash session

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

I'm writing a script that is going exec a new bash session. Based on some logic, it finds an init script that will be used for the new shell. I'm wondering if there is a nice way to tell the new bash session to use the found init script for initialization *in addition to* the system initialization scripts. The --init-file option seems to call for a replacement file rather than an additional one.

Currently, I've got a messy setup with an environment variable containing the path to the found init scrip which gets sourced in a wrapper init file, along with the system files. Is something like 
`exec bash --init-file "/etc/profile;~/.bashrc;${myInit}"` possible?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: I don't believe I have enough "points" to comment on withoutasound's answer, so I'll do it here. I think what your suggesting is similar to the "wrapper init" file I'm working with right now. What I'd love to be able to do is source all of the files I know I'll need at the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This stands a good chance of working:

```
exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc "${myInit}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this on my machine, but perhaps you could pass a custom .bashrc or .bash_profile to your subshell, sourcing the 'init' file with something like

```
if [ -f path_to_init ]; then
  . path_to_init_file
fi
```